# Alternatives to Job Sequencing using Optimization

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, artificial-intelligence

I have to N jobs to be assigned in a sequence to a Machine/User. I know using optimization technique we can find an optimal sequence. But in my case there are lot of parameters (some to be minimized (time) , some to be maximized (profit etc)). So I am wondering if there any alternative methods to rank the jobs.

It would be great if anyone can suggest some Machine learning method so that there is no need to update the optimization equation as new variables come in.

In case if someone is wondering what Job sequencing is: http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~kabanets/307/sched307.pdf

Comment: You might want to look into some standard Operations Research techniques for job scheduling. There are a lot of fast algorithms for your problem that have performance guarantees of $\leq 2$ for easy cases.

Comment: @JeremiasK can you suggest few techniques or a good starting point?

Comment: To add to @Jeremias' aswer, if you have several hard constraints that need to be satisfied then [Integer Programming](http://web.mit.edu/15.053/www/AMP-Chapter-09.pdf) might be a better technique. It will allow you to tradeoff different objectives and ensure that constraints ( like finishing the job before due date etc.) are satisfied.